# show exceptions in statusbar

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, statusbar

I have an application where the user can type in some data. Then it will be validated and if the validation fails an exception will be thrown. Is it possible to show this exception in the statusbar? So that the user knows what is wrong.

I hope you can help me..... again :S

Comment: What do you need help with, specifically?

Comment: The best way to solve this would likely be with an MVVM pattern design, and possibly (depending on your needs) an error messenger service.

Comment: I should maybe have mentioned it but I already have an mvvm pattern implemented

Comment: If you have further questions about it, just ask and I'll try to add it to my answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..? Catch the validation exception and set the statusbar text property?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the StatusBar control in your xaml file:

```
<StatusBar Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="myStatusBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
     <StatusBarItem x:Name="errorStatusBarItem" Content="No errors" />
</StatusBar>
```

Throwing exceptions and then catching them to update the text can work, but I would suggest not to use exceptions in this situation. Instead, you can create an event updating text in the status bar and invoke it or just set the text directly (if the application is simple enough). Either way, you can do it this way:

```
errorStatusBarItem.Content = "error message"; //or something like err.Message if you are using method with exceptions
```

If you need more details about other methods, I can add it.

Comment: hmm. How do I catch the exception in the view model? It can possibly be thrown from any other place.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant MVVM pattern or something else. If it's possible, you can implement a generic handler for all unhandled exceptions in your application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx.